# Complete the series:

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, number-sequence, sequence

$4427, 827, 67, 31, 9, ?$

Choose between:

- (a): $7$
- (b): $6$
- (c): $5$
- (d): $4$

Looking at the numbers I think that there must be some exponential relationship but couldn't find it. I took the sequence of differences between the numbers which is $3600, 760, 36, 22, ?$ 
But I still couldn't find any relationship.

I do not think the question is wrong.

*Source : [NTSE Test Series, MAT](https://www.scribd.com/document/412656948/NTSE-Test-Stage-2-1-Final)*

Answer (score 7):

The answer maybe:

> (a): 7

The reason is:

> ```
> 4427 = 672 - 2 × 31
>  827 = 312 - 2 × 67
>
>   67 =  92 - 2 ×  7
>   31 =  72 - 2 ×  9
> ```
>
> I don't think this is just a coincidence :)